# Using subprocess.Popen (shell=True) with windows folders

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm currently looking at `Popen` to automate the compression & storage of documents.

For the compression part, I thought of the following Python line:

```
subprocess.Popen("WinRAR.exe a -r c:\\03. Notes\\AllTexts *.txt", shell=True)
```

I keep having error messages, as the command is not able to deal with a folder name that contains a space (`03. Notes`).
This question was asked before several times, and, I must say that I tried all propositions: raw string, double quotes, triple quotes, ... None of them worked.

As I can't change the folder names, and I have no more ideas to try, could someone advise how could I possibly pass this command line successfully ?

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True` at all? Could you use `list` based invocation (with the `glob` module to expand your glob), and let Python do the necessary conversions/escaping automatically, without using `shell=True`?

Comment: There is no reason to use the shell for this command. Use an argument list without the shell, e.g. `subprocess.check_call(["WinRAR.exe", "a", "-r", r"C:\03. Notes\AllTexts", "*.txt"])`.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. The check_call makes a lot of sense, as the list of arguments is much longer than in my example. I don't know how to mark your comment has valuable answer, but it actually helped a lot. It restored hope in my automation project :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows you should use quotes for file or directory names (if you want to use spaces inside). In Python, you should escape quotes with \ symbol (if you are using strings inside " quotes). Like this:

```
"my name is \"Mark\"!"
```

Or just:

```
'my name is "Mark"!'
```

So this will work as expected:

```
subprocess.Popen("WinRAR.exe a -r \"c:\\03. Notes\\AllTexts\" *.txt", shell=True)
```

As well as:

```
subprocess.Popen('WinRAR.exe a -r "c:\\03. Notes\\AllTexts" *.txt', shell=True)
```

Comment: The use of raw strings within strings is something new to me. I tweaked the code, and it worked just fine. Thanks for the hint. I tried also the check_call method mentioned by eryksun above. I am now comparing the 2 methods. The check_call looks a bit easier to read and less 'treacherous' in terms of counting back-slashes. Anyways, I moved from "no more idea to test" to "2 options to compare" in 6 hours. Thanks a lot.